# const_cast vs mutable and undefined behavior

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, mutable, const-cast

**Edit**: I edited the code here to not use pointers because there were too many unrelated comments about it

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo(const int a) : total(a) {}

    int       index = 0;
    const int total;
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(const int a) : total(a) {}

    mutable int index = 0;
    const int   total;
};

int main() {
    const Foo foo(3);
    for (
        ;
        foo.index < foo.total;
        const_cast<Foo*>(&foo)->index++ // 1. Undefined behavior because foo is const
    )
        std::cout << "Foo " << foo.index << std::endl;

    const Bar bar(3);
    for (
        ;
        bar.index < bar.total;
        bar.index++ // 2. Not undefined behavior because of mutable?
    )
        std::cout << "Bar " << bar.index << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To the best of my knowledge the line labeled with `// 1. Undefined behavior because foo is const` is undefined behavior because `foo` is a `const` object and `const_cast` is being used to modify the object anyway

However I am uncertain if there is any possible undefined behavior related to the line labeled with `// 2. Not undefined behavior because of mutable?`. It essentially is achieving the same result by using `mutable` instead of `const_cast`

My question then is whether there are cases where a `const` object with `mutable` members can cause undefined behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mutable member subobject of a const object is itself not a const object and none of the special rules for const objects, such as not being allowed to modify it, apply to it.

The containing complete object and other non-mutable subobjects of that subobject, recursively, are still const objects and so may not be modified.

The definition of *const object* can be found in [[basic.type.qualifier/1.1]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.type.qualifier#1.1) of the standard:

> (1.1) A *const object* is an object of type `const T` or a non-mutable subobject of a const object.

So modifying the `mutable` member subobject or any of its subobjects is always fine, even if the containing object is `const`, but this applies *only* to the mutable member. Whether any `const_cast` is involved is irrelevant.

However, this is only covers actual *modification* of the mutable subobject, i.e. built-in assignment to itself or one of its (scalar) subobjects. What is still not permitted is to *replace* the mutable subobject via placement-new with a new object. The relevant rule about replacing const objects is that no new objects may be placed in any storage that has been or will be occupied by a const-complete object of automatic, static or thread-local storage duration. In your case `bar` is a const object and a complete object. It has automatic storage duration and the mutable subobject occupies part of its storage.

Answer (score 7):

A `mutable` field is never const and thus can never invoke UB with const_cast. It is not the same behavior because theoretically #1 could place index in rom

Comment: My concern is that `foo` is a `const` object and `mutable` essentially means that `const` object still mutates. Does `mutable` prevent the compiler from making assumptions about the object overall not being modified or just that member?

Comment: @asimes Just that member. When it is `mutable` it is not `const`. The compiler will not assume that it is `const`

Comment: @asimes A `mutable` member subobject of a const object is itself not a const object and none of the special rules for const objects (such as not being allowed to modify it) apply to it. The containing object and other non-mutable subobjects are still const objects and so may not be modified. (See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.type.qualifier#1.1 in the standard.)

Comment: @user17732522 That might be worth making its own answer